# Making breakout game in three.js - detect end of the board

Tags: three.js

i'm trying to learn Three.js by making game, sadly most resources I would be interested in are outdated, since library seem to change so often.

Currently I am able to move my paddle with my mouse and launch the ball on mouse click, however I've got no clue how to stop paddle to go over the board and make ball bounce from the edges.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my current code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);

//renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


//board
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 6, 0.00001)
material= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "blue"});
var board = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);


scene.add(board);


//paddle
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 0.1, 0.2);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "red" });
var paddle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

paddle.position.set(0, -2.5, 0);
scene.add(paddle);


camera.position.z = 5;

//ball
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
ball.moving = false;
ball.position.set(0, -2.3, 0);

var velocityY = 0.05; //ball Y speed

scene.add(ball);


//mouse movements
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove(e) {
    mouse.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    paddle.position.x = mouse.x * 5.5;
}

function onMouseClick(e) {
    ball.moving = true;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('click', onMouseClick, false);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // ball.position.y += -0.01;

    if (ball.moving === false) {
        // console.log('jest false')
        ball.position.x = paddle.position.x;
    } else {
        ball.position.y += velocityY;
        ball.position.x += 0.01;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here:
https://threejs.org/editor/

Load the arkanoid example..

Select the Scene object in the list on the right...
Click edit on the Game Logic script at the bottom...

Comment: Thank you, I will dissect this code and try to figure it out :)